# Grepped /sys/ directory, now device won't respond

Tags: ssh, grep, sudo, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recursively grepped the /sys/ directory for the string "hello" over SSH:

`sudo grep -r hello /sys/`

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4B 8gig. After performing this command, the rpi won't respond to pings, all websites running on it are down, and I can't ssh to it (error code 225).

I don't have acess to the device at the moment, but when I do, will restarting fix the problem? And what happened?

Thanks.

Comment: It could have happened, maybe you polled something which resulted in a temporary HW fault. Restarting will help, no need to worry.

Comment: (1) What `grep` are you using? If it's busybox `grep`, I'm not sure whether `-r` option will follow symbolic links (which would be a bad idea in recursive file systems like `/sys`). (2) Reading access to device drivers may cause unexpected actions, but those will likely only last until the next restart.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what did you want to achieve by using this exact command?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I was following a guide on https://linuxhint.com/what_is_dev_null/, and it gave an example of how to use /dev/null to ignore errors; grep -r hello /sys/. Out of curiosity I ran the command with sudo.